# Mobile not recognising @media formatting

Tags: html, mobile, formatting, screen, media

I have formatted my website for mobile phones, however on testing, find that my mobile devices still refer to the normal format webpage.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<!-- SMARTPHONES, PORTRAIT & LANDSCAPE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 641px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)" href="mobile.css" />

<!-- NETBOOKS UP TO DESKTOPS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-height: 750px)" href="netbook.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (min-height: 751px)" href="common.css" />
<link id="Link1" rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link id="Link2" rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

The website is http://www.interimspaces.co.uk

Any thoughts...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missed it but i don't see

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable = no">
```

in the head of your website.